# Convert individually all the lists to dataframe within a loop

Tags: r

I have assigned a lists to inside the loop. The lists has many dataframe of unequal length and different column names. But even though I convert lists to dataframe, the output is still coming as lists only . Below is my code

```
   fv <- structure(list(values = c("A&C", "A&E", "C&E"), v1 = c("A", "A", 
   "C"), v2 = c("C", "E", "E")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = 
   "data.frame")

    df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 2L), .Label = c("asd", "dfg", "fgdsgd", 
    "fsd", "gdfgd", "gs", "sdfg", "sf"), class = "factor"), B = c(29L, 
    24L, 46L, 50L, 43L, 29L, 32L, 24L, 35L, 39L, 33L, 47L, 53L, 26L, 
    31L), C = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 
    2L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", 
    "gfg", "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), D = c(36L, 56L, 
    39L, 26L, 56L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 45L, 34L, 27L, 43L, 40L, 56L
    ), E = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
    9L, 8L, 8L, 4L), .Label = c("asd", "er", "fg", "gf", "gfd", "gfg", 
    "qw", "sf", "tr"), class = "factor"), F = c(44L, 34L, 37L, 23L, 
    37L, 51L, 28L, 36L, 33L, 31L, 39L, 43L, 25L, 37L, 43L)), class = 
   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
   -15L))

io <- list()
asd <- list()
for(i in 1:nrow(fv))
{ io[[i]] <- tapply(df[,fv$v1[i]], df[,fv$v2[i]], FUN = function(x) 
length(unique(x)))
}

for(i in 1:nrow(fv))
{ asd[[i]] <- stack(unlist(io[i]))
colnames(asd[[i]]) <- c(fv$v1[i],fv$v2[i])
asd[[i]] <- data.frame(asd[[i]]) }
```

DO not worry about the data objects above. The code is all good expect last line asd[[i]] <- data.frame(asd[[i]]). Because below is the output i get.Its a lists and I need it in a data frame. There are 2 examples below

```
    asd[2]
    [[1]]
       A   E
     1 1 asd
     2 2  er
     3 2  fg
     4 1  gf
     5 1 gfd
     6 2 gfg
     7 1  qw
     8 3  sf
     9 2  tr

     asd[1]
     [[1]]
      A   C
    1 1 asd
    2 2  er
    3 2  fg
    4 1  gf
    5 1 gfd
    6 2 gfg
    7 1  qw
    8 3  sf
    9 2  tr
```

Instead I Need like this a dataframe. Hope my points are clear

```
       asd[2]
       A   E
     1 1 asd
     2 2  er
     3 2  fg
     4 1  gf
     5 1 gfd
     6 2 gfg
     7 1  qw
     8 3  sf
     9 2  tr

     asd[1]
      A   C
    1 1 asd
    2 2  er
    3 2  fg
    4 1  gf
    5 1 gfd
    6 2 gfg
    7 1  qw
    8 3  sf
    9 2  tr
```

Comment: Try `unlist(asd, recursive=FALSE)`

Comment: Is it within the loop ?

Comment: I tried. It is still showing as list only

Comment: No, just run it afterwards. If you want someone to look at your loop. you need to make your question more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have edited and added datasets of "fv" and "df"

Comment: Good, but replace your edit with the outputs of `dput(head(fv))` and `dput(head(df))`, otherwise I miss the structure of your data and can't help you.

Comment: I can't find the relation between your input and output. From where is `SUP OFFICE` or `XG6` or `AQ5` coming ?

Comment: Ronak :) sorry. I missed it and I have edited my output

Comment: This is not a `dput`. And your code yields data frames in un-nested lists for me. This is very unclear at the moment.

Comment: Oops. I had changed it but was not reflecting. Now I have changed it. please check

Comment: I think this is difficult to solve

Comment: It's still not clear to me how you arrive at your output from your input. What is the logic of it? When I run your `for` loop I don't get the output you have shown. Also `asd[1]` and `asd[2]` you have shown are just same.

Comment: Don't you want `asd[[1]]` and `asd[[2]]` with two `[[`?

Comment: Rui. Perfect thanks a lot. I did not know it was too simple :)